# Как правильно размонтировать шару samba через systemd при выключении компа?

Tags: linux, share, samba, mount, systemd

Есть systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=home storage folder
After=remote-fs-pre.target
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
BindsTo=network-online.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target

[Mount]
What=//172.16.100.1/storage
Where=/home/username/Shared/storage
Type=cifs
Options=noauto,x-systemd.automount,noexec,noperm,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/etc/share_creds/home_samba

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

Монтируется Замечательно. Размонтируется через `systemctl stop` вообще без нарекарий.
Но если с подмонтированной шарой выключить или рестартануть комп, то подвисает на полторы минуты на попытке размонтирования.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону ковырять, чтобы избавиться от подвисания при выключении.

**UPD**
Пара уточнений:
1. Kubuntu 18.04.1
2. Естественно сетью рулит NetworkManager

**UUPD**
С благодарностью приму решения как отловить момент перед разрывом WiFi соединения, для того, чтобы впихнуть перед ним команду на размонтирование.

Пока получается только так:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ deactivating ]] && {
        /bin/systemctl stop home-username-Shared-storage.mount
    }
done < <(LANG=en_US nmcli monitor)
```

> НО. Опять же. При тестировании работает. Тоесть если я вручную запускаю этот скрипт, монтирую шару запуская `systemctl start home-username-Shared-storage.mount` то при отключении WiFi шара великолепным образом размонтируется. Но если отправить машину в ребут, опять зависание на полторы минуты с попыткой размонтировать шару.

**UUUPD** В качастве костыля пока придумал дописать в `[Mount] TimeoutSec=5` При этом размонтирование через 5 сек просто завершается с ошибкой и комп дальше спокойно ребутится. Но если есть способ более красивый, чем просто задушить процесс umount то буду благодарен за подсказку.

Comment: а логи смотрел, в каком порядке там на самом деле отключается и кто именно виснет?

Comment: Виснет назмонтирование. Оно об этом пишет. В логах тоже только про размонтирование. Такое впечатление, что при ребуте или выключении NM просто киляет сам себя (хотя какое впечатление, у него в юните буквами по монитору прописано `KillMode=process`.) и никакими событиями по этому поводу не заморачивается. Попробовал поймать событие из `nmcli monitor` но там тоже при ребуте молчок

Comment: *на размонтировании (опечутка вс...лась)

Comment: я бы посмотрел именно на **порядок** действий в логах: если проблема из-за того, что NM прибивается раньше отмонтирования, то проблема скорей всего в юните, если нет, то может быть она глубже...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем как говорят умные люди "курите маны". Маны рулят!!!
Изначально ставилась задача получить в доступ папки на домашнем сервере и избавиться от подвисаний при неожиданном обрыве связи.

Имелись следующие вводные:

> 1) Маленький домашний серверок.
>   2) На нем есть файлы которые бывают нужны и редактируются то с домашнего компа, то с ноутбука да и не всегда мной, а версии хочется иметь актуальные всегда под рукой.
>   3) Там-же поднят VPN сервер на базе OpenVPN (соответственно внешний IP для подключения в наличии)
>   4) Есть Ноутбук с Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS и соответственно сетью на нем рулит NetworkManager естественно если нахожусь не дома то подключение к серверу через VPN
>   5) Часто, где-то вне дома, подключаюсь через телефон.

Так вот. Если в момент когда я залез в папку и что-то там делаю или просто забыл закрыть ее мне кто-нибудь позвонит, то файл менеджер виснет наглухо, впольть до жесткого перезапуска.

Уже в процессе изучения вопроса находил много ссылок на `autofs` но хотелось не бросать идею реализовать все это через найтивный (уже теперь) `systemd`

Если кому-то пригодится буду рад. Так-же с радостью приму конструктивную критику и дельные советы знающих людей относительно реализации этой задачи.

Собствено то, что получилось:

`mkdir -p ~/Shared/storage`
`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/home-<username>-Shared-storage.automount`

```
[Unit]
Description=automounts home storage share
Requires=NetworkManager.service home-connection-monitor.service

[Automount]
Where=/home/<username>/Shared/storage
TimeoutIdleSec=301

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

---

`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/home-<username>-Shared-storage.mount`

```
[Unit]
Description=home storage folder
Requires=NetworkManager.service home-connection-monitor.service
After=home-connection-monitor.service

[Mount]
What=//<local-share-ip>/storage
Where=/home/<username>/Shared/storage
Type=cifs
Options=nofail,_netdev,noauto,iocharset=utf8,uid=<user_uid>,gid=<user_gid>,credentials=</path/to/file/with/credentials>
ForceUnmount=yes
LazyUnmount=yes
TimeoutSec=5
```

---

`sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/home-connection-monitor.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=home connection monitor
After=home-<username>-Shared-storage.automount
Requires=NetworkManager.service home-<username>-Shared-storage.automount

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/home-connection-monitor
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

---

`sudo vi /usr/local/bin/home-connection-monitor`

```
#!/bin/bash
host='<local-share-ip>'
vpn_connection_name='<yor-vpn-connection-name>'
test_internet_host='208.67.222.222' # к примеру, можно любой доступный только через интернет.

connect_to_home()
{
    printf '%s\n' "$(date +"%d_%m_%Y %H:%M:%S") Trying connecting to ${host}" # Задел на будущее для создания лог файла
    until ping -W2 -c1 "${test_internet_host}" &>/dev/null; do
        ping -W1 -c1 "${host}"  &>/dev/null && break
        sleep 1
    done
    ping -W1 -c1 "${host}"  &>/dev/null && {
        printf "$(date +"%d_%m_%Y %H:%M:%S") Connection for ${host} [ \\e[32m%s\\e[m ]\\n" 'established'
        return 0
    }
    until ping -W1 -c1 "${host}" &>/dev/null; do

        if nmcli con up "${vpn_connection_name}"; then
            if ping -W1 -c1 "${host}" &>/dev/null; then
                printf "$(date +"%d_%m_%Y %H:%M:%S") Connection for ${host} [ \\e[32m%s\\e[m ]\\n" 'established'
                return 0
            fi
        else
            sleep 2
        fi

    done
}

connect_to_home && {
    while ping -W1 -c1 "${host}" &>/dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
    exit 1
}
```

---

> **ВАЖНО!!!** все между <и> заменить своими данными
>   **ВАЖНО!!!** файлы .mount и .automount имеют имена соответствующие пути точки монтирования то есть если путь точки монтирования `/media/samba` то эти файлы должны называться `media-samba.mount` и `media-samba.automount`

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl enable home-karpovan-Shared-storage.{,auto}mount`
`sudo systemctl enable home-connection-monitor`